# ¿Cómo puedo sustituir la última ocurrencia de un carácter en una cadena?

Tags: bash, unix

Necesito sustituir o cambiar la salida mediante el último delimitador de una oración.

Por ejemplo tengo esto:

```
/hola/mundo/text.txt
/hola/text.txt
/text.txt
/hola/mundo/archivos/text.txt
```

Necesito tabular text.txt mediante el delimitador "/" para separar la ruta del archivo en dos columnas.

Como pueden ver no siempre el último delimitador estará en la misma ruta, entonces tengo dos opciones:

- Hacer la tabulación con el último delimitador.
- Sustituir el último delimitador por otro y así luego ordenarlo manualmente mediante otra herramienta.

Comment: ¿quieres sustituir la ultima ocurrencia del slash por un tabulador?

Comment: la idea es que tengo eso en un csv, entonces, quiero ordenarlo por columnas, pero, necesito ya darle una tabulacion o sustituir el ultimo slash por otro caracter para este usarlo luego como delimitador y separar la ruta del archivo en 2 columnas

Comment: lo sustituyo por asterisco usando el comando sed

Comment: `cat archivo |sed 's/\(.*\)\//\1*/'`

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, me podrias explicar un poco que es lo que hace para entenderlo

Comment: ¿Cuál debe ser la salida exactamente? En particular, para `/text.txt`,  ¿quieres `/   text.txt` o solamente `text.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)\//\1*/' archivo
/hola/mundo*text.txt
/hola*text.txt
*text.txt
/hola/mundo/archivos*text.txt
```

El comando sed permite sustituir caracteres en las líneas de un archivo.

- `s/\(.*\)\/` busca la ultima ocurrencia del carácter '/'. Antes de este se usa el caracter de escape '\' para evitar errores al ejecutar el comando.
- `/\1*/'` imprime el grupo capturado con `\(.*\)` seguido de un asterisco.

Los caracteres como "\" y "/" deben ser precedidos por el caracter de escape en el comando sed.

Comment: Nótese que `cat fichero | sed '...'` también se puede decir `sed '...' fichero`

Comment: Seguramente sea más legible `sed -r 's|(.*)/|\1*|'`. Fíjate que en lugar de `/` utilizo otro delimitador (en este caso "|", pero [podría ser casi cualquier otro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33914360/1983854)). Con la extensión `-r` puedes capturar `()` sin tener que escapar.

Answer (score 1):

Tu fichero consiste en una serie de rutas de ficheros. Dado que quieres separar la ruta del nombre, ¿qué mejor que utilizar las herramientas que vienen de serie para obtener estos datos?

En efecto, `dirname` te da la ruta y `basename` el nombre del fichero:

```
$ dirname "/hola/que/tal/estas.txt"
/hola/que/tal
$ basename "/hola/que/tal/estas.txt"
estas.txt
```

Por tanto, podemos hacer un bucle de toda la vida e ir separando estos valores:

```
while IFS= read -r linea
do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" $(dirname "$linea") $(basename "$linea")
done < fichero
```

En tu caso nos devolvería:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do printf "%s\t%s\n" $(dirname "$line") $(basename "$line"); done < fichero
/hola/mundo text.txt
/hola   text.txt
/   text.txt
/hola/mundo/archivos    text.txt
```

También puedes conseguir lo mismo utilizando la [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) ([origen de la idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187920/40596)):

```
while IFS= read -r linea
do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "${linea%/*}" "${linea##*/}"
done < fichero
```